# Excel - Automatically change input cell value and export output cells to new workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I can enter a reference number and Excel generates a table based on the data tied to that reference number.

Rather than enter each reference number individually and copy the resulting table manually, is it possible to automatically iterate the process of entering the reference numbers (from an existing list) and exporting the results separately?

Comment: The short answer is yes, just need to know what's to happen for each reference # (make table in new sheet, in a different workbook, etc).  It sounds like you have the first part already coded (generate a table from a reference #)?

Comment: What I have at the moment is a table that updates based on the reference number provided. What I'd like is for each reference number to be entered automatically, and export the updated table each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Idea:

I didn't quite understand HOW you need to automatically enter those reference, but a good idea would be writing all the numbers you need in a .txt file, then program a button which loads a `msoFileDialogFilePicker` to select your file. When the file is selected, you can open it with a `New FileSystemObject`, read it with `ReadLine` and filling an array with all the numbers you have written in the .txt file. Then with a `for`cycle from `LBound`to `UBound`of that array you can enter those numbers automatically in your `Range`.

To export everytime your results table (which again I didn't quite understand HOW you want it to be exported), an idea would be a `Worksheet Change`event (if the results table appear in your spreadsheet) in which you can write down some code to copy-paste the results table in a new worksheet and then save it, or make a .pdf of the results table from its area.

The possibilities are really too many to write a single piece of code to show you :)

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary to set up a .txt file for can I use a list in a separate worksheet? As for how to export, I think exporting the whole worksheet is probably best.

Comment: You are welcome. Naturally, filling an array from a number list in a separate worksheet would be even easier: simply `set` the source worksheet in a variable, an fill the array with the data in `Source.Range("XX")`where XX is one of N ranges where your numbers are.
EDIT: By the way, if your next question is "can I pass a closed worksheet to a variable?", the answer would be "no" :) You need to open the source worksheet in order to access its data. But no worries: you can always `Application.ScreenUpdate = False` to show not the worksheet you've just opened

Comment: As for export, you can just copy-paste the newly calculated table in a new workbook ( `Set TargetBook = Application.Workbooks.Add` ) and then save it with a name you like ( `Targetbook.Close(True, YourNameHere)`)